# Webpage background on mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, media, device

On my website, I set the current background CSS proprieties:

```
/* General */   
body {
    background-image: url('../img/background2.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    color:#000; /* Font color */
    text-align:justify;
}
```

And it's fine on my laptop, but when I'm trying to visit the website on my tablet (Nexus 7) or on my smartphone (Samsung Galaxy S3) the background appears stretched in height, I mean in the full length of the page.

I've tried media queries, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Setting "background-size: 100% 100%;" will only work when the device has the same aspect ratio as the image.  It locks the background's width and height to fill the entire screen.  Try "background-size: cover;" or "background-size: contain;".  Documentation on those can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp).

**EDIT:** Be aware that this is only compatible on IE9+, and you need the -webkit- prefix on older Android browsers (see [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size) for details).

Comment: The "contain" tip did the trick but doesn't fixed the background. As I scroll down, the background disappears. Although has the proprieties         background-repeat:no-repeat;
       background-attachment:fixed;

Comment: You're scrolling out of range of the containing element.  Even <body> ends after a while.  You'll need to declare a height and width to the body element.

Comment: If you declare your <body> to be fixed and lock the height and width to 100%, it will always fill the viewport, though you may want to use a <div> instead of <body> so that you don't run into any z-index issues.

Comment: although i've already assigned proprieties height:100%; width:100%; on my phone it doesn't fixed the background.

Comment: What do you mean by "not fixed?"  It doesn't fill the viewport, or it is distorted?  If it doesn't fill the viewport, use "background-size:cover;" instead of "background-size:contain;".  If it is distorted, then you are probably declaring some sort of size property somewhere else.

Comment: So, on the phone, the contain propriety do what i need it to do by resize the bg image both in height and width. Does not fixate the image, I mean, when i scroll down, the background get out of the viewport. I need it to stay fix. The cover doesn't resize the image in either device (laptop, smartphone or tablet)

Comment: Ah, you mean fixed as in unmoving.  You need to set the containing element to "position: fixed;" in order to keep that from happening.

Comment: but when i setup position propriety i can't scroll on the page. I  want to scroll on the page, just don't want the background to scroll with the page.

Comment: Set the image as the background of a div, set width:100% and height:100%, position:fixed, and z-index:-10.  Everything else should be above it on the page.

Comment: nop... didn't work also... the position fixed is messing up with scroll. i can't understand what's wrong... it seems that google chrome on the Galaxy S3 doesn't recognize the  background-attachment:fixed; ...  that would fix everything...

Comment: You also might not be "scrolling" when you do this, but panning across the page.  Try adding this to the header:

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>

Comment: doesn't do anything also.... we should talk about this further but i can't chat, don't have reputation... it seems the problem is in the android/phone/tablet, because, on the laptop and other browsers, everuthing works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In my experiences, the background-size works with pixels on mobile browsers.

```
body {
    background-size: 800px 600px;
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but try:

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: nop... thanks, but until now, the closest solution relies on contain propriety.